# Removing rows where a field has repeating digits in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have a query that returns customer phone numbers. Many of the numbers are bogus or invalid, where the customer has put in all 9's, all 1's, all 0's or a combination of both. How can I go about removing rows where the Phone numbers have x amount of recurring digits to where I can eliminate the invalid numbers and only show rows with valid numbers?

I put this in my where clause but I don't think it's the best way to go about it.

`where C.XBW-CELL-PHONE not in (0,9999999999,1111111111,1111110000)`

```
 All Phone Numbers
 --------------
 9999999999
 9990000000
 1111111111
 9545205889
 8008772321
 1110001100
 9991111111


 Valid Phone Numbers
 --------------
 9545205889
 8008772321
```

Comment: What is your rules to say that a number is invalid ? Because it is possible to have a number with all same number except one, I'm wrong ? If you want to use regex, you need to determine a format in natural language to be able translate into regex.

Comment: Sadly MySQL (at least the version I have here) doesn't support /^([0-9])(\1){5,}$/ (which is what I'd use elsewhere to perform such a match - specifically \1 is a back reference to the first matching pattern. MariaDB has a full PCRE implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
 where C.XBW-CELL-PHONE not like '%000%' and
 not like '%111%' and
 not like '%222%' and
 not like '%333%' and
 not like '%444%' and
 not like '%555%' and
 not like '%666%' and
 not like '%777%' and
 not like '%888%' and
 not like '%999%';
```

But I think you should probably test on 4 consecutive digits, 3 might remove real numbers.

Comment: This works for me. Four digits is perfect. I'll probably just pipe whatever I have to a CSV and create an awk script to trim the invalid numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Valid ones:

```
WHERE   phone RLIKE '[2345678]'   -- existence of those digits --> allowed
   OR ( phone RLIKE '0' ) AND
      ( phone RLIKE '1' ) AND
      ( phone RLIKE '9' )         -- all 3 of [019] --> allowed
```

If you want to use 4-digits, then change the 0,1,9 to 0000,1111,9999

If '2222223333' is supposed to be invalid, then you failed to point that out in your Question.

History lesson.  When US area codes first came into existence, they were limited to the regexp

```
[2-9][01][2-9]
```

And the next 3 digits could not look like an area code.